# How does variance work when implementing interfaces/type aliases in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, covariance, variance

I have the following types :

```js
interface Config {
    configurable: boolean;
    cancelable: boolean;
    isUnique: boolean;
}

// Config Subtype
interface EnvironmentConfig extends Config {
    runtime: 'DEV' | 'PROD';
}

// Config Subtype
interface AnalogConfig extends Config {
    pulse: boolean;
}

enum ConfigKeys {
    initConfig = 0,
    customConfig = 1
}

type Run = {
    [Key in ConfigKeys]?: (config: Config) => Config
}
```

If I want to implement `Run` in a class, it throws an error, since when implementing it it only allows me to define the type `Config`, it could not specify a subtype of `Config`:

```js
class Runner implements Run {
    [1](config: SpecialConfig) { // Error
        return config
    }

    [1](config: Config) { // Ok!
        return config
    }
}
```

How can I get it to allow me to declare a subtype of `Config` when implementing the `Run` type alias?

Is there any way? What other alternative can I apply?

Comment: •Please [edit] to make the code a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you’re seeing without having to deal with unrelated problems like undeclared types/values. • Covariant method parameters are unsafe. Why do you want to introduce it to your code? Could you make `IASTVisitor` generic in the subtype of `Node` instead?

Comment: Is there a predictable relationship between the key and the subtype of `Config` you want to support for that key? Or could different implementations of `Run` make different choices for the same keys?

Comment: ...and what's `SpecialConfig`? I'd love to suggest something but without a [mre] or a description of how arbitrary or predictable the relationship between the key and the `Config` subtype is, it becomes just random guesses.  You could do [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxEb1W), maybe that's what you want? Who knows. Please [edit] to make it clear what the goal is, with use cases and where any type mentioned is either provided by TS or declared by you.